# Never turn off Windows

Tags: windows, battery

My Surface has an issue with the power button; it doesn't make contact properly. To turn it on, I have to try clicking it often for more than 10 minutes before it powers on.

Fixing it is as expensive as buying a new one. I turned off battery saver, but it happens it turns off and I cannot turn it on again. The only way is for it to go sleep and click some keys on the keyboard to turn it "on" again.

How can it never turn off (only when the battery is at 0%)?

Comment: [How to Turn on Your PC with Your Android Phone Using **Wake-On-LAN**](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-pc-android-phone-wakeonlan/). Possible from _IPhone_ as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Surface devices are very difficult to repair.
If you have another computer, you could use
[Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) (WoL)
via your local network to wake it up from that computer.
Some routers also have the capability to issue WoL.
This is not an ideal solution, but it can enable using the Surface
for some time.

Download and install `SurfaceWOL.msi` from the
[Microsoft Download Center - Surface Tools for IT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46703&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7809_1246483&tduid=%28ir__pkli1rhdtwkfr2ta0er6am96sn2xm0nqihl01wjt00%29%287809%29%281246483%29%28%283c50eea7406361a516efe7a3f78cdd95%29%28152407%29%281806294%29%2884412X1536482X53ec34a25c1da338291fcbe6a92c2cd9%29%28%29%29%283c50eea7406361a516efe7a3f78cdd95%29&irclickid=_pkli1rhdtwkfr2ta0er6am96sn2xm0nqihl01wjt00)
to enable WoL on the Surface.
The Surface device must be connected to AC power and connected to the
network using its Ethernet adapter for WoL to work.

To wake the Surface, you may use a
[PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/wake-on-lan-815424c4),
a [Windows Store app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/wake-on-lan/9wzdncrdfshb),
or any other third-party tool, such as
[SolarWinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/wake-on-lan).
You will need your Surface MAC address, which you can find using the
command `ipconfig /all`.

For information see:

- [Wake On LAN for Surface devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/wake-on-lan-for-surface-devices)
  by Microsoft.
- [How to enable Wake-On-Lan on Surface devices on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/wake-on-lan-surface-windows-10/)
  Supplies the same information as the Microsoft link, but with more detail
  and screenshots.

Comment: > Surface devices are very difficult to repair < I've been told, yes... I will look into your suggestion

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill: The Microsoft post will not disappear as long as the Surface is supported, and then it won't matter.

Comment: @harrymc Microsoft links become invalid all the time as they update the website. You should know by now  that answer must be self-contained.

Comment: @DavidPostill: OK, did it. Argumentative: by extension, you might also ask to upload to SU the Microsoft files in case their links disappear as well.

Comment: I'm considering this. I don't know why it's been downvoted like this. Many thanks

Comment: Downvoting is sometimes social in nature. WoL is the only alternative I could come up with to scraping the Surface.

Comment: Does WoL only work on sleep/hibernate? If it reaches 0% and shuts down, it won't work, will it?

Comment: If Windows 10 has detected the battery is empty and has shut down correctly, this will work once connected to main power and your network. You should have enabled [Fast startup](https://lifehacker.com/enable-this-setting-to-make-windows-10-boot-up-faster-1743697169), which is on by default. If Windows doesn't detect the battery-empty condition fast enough to close down in an orderly manner, you may increase the [critical battery level](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-critical-low-level-battery-action-windows-8-7).

Comment: Downvoted for no reason I see. This is the only solution posted so far here and I like the idea. I will try it.

Comment: @harrymc also perhaps you meant "You should have **disabled** Fast startup"

Comment: You might try both. My thinking was that fast startup is the modern standby, so WoL should work with it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your system never to be turned off, the solution is simple: keep it plugged and running 24/7.

However, I suggest fixing the power button or buying a new system. The electricity costs will outweigh in the long run, solving the problem.

Comment: The battery works and I take notes with it in class.

Comment: Great. Keep it on battery until it's almost depleted, then plug it in somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achive it, is to use a mouse-mover-program which moves your mouse every couple of minutes one pixel forward and back. i think you can find some
on google, but try to get it from secure sources, or if possible, code it by yourself.

The other way is to setup your BIOS and/or OS-settings.